# rails 3, how can I run a loop n.times where the value of n is set by local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This should be fairly simply...

I have Recommendations has_many Assets.

I want to limit the user to adding 3 Assets per Recommendation, and I can do this simply by limiting the number of fields show.

In my new action in the controller I am doing a very simple:

```
3.times {@recommendation.assets.build}
```

In my edit action I am trying to build the logic to decide how many fields to show:

```
@assets = @recommendation.assets.all
if @assets.empty?
  3.times {@recommendation.assets.build}
else
  asset_loop = @assets.count - 3 
  asset_loop.times {@recommendation.assets.build}
end
```

The if works but the else does not.  How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal, you just need to change

```
asset_loop = @assets.count - 3
```

to

```
asset_loop = 3 - @assets.count
```

Do make sure to validate the incoming data if you want to truly enforce the limit. Otherwise you're at the mercy of anyone with a web console and curl.